# Inputs in Angular Material 2 tab labels doesn't allow spaces

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an input in the tab label and noticed that it doesn't allow spaces. I tried the `event.stopPropagation();` but it didn't work. Is there a workaround?

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      Tab Label: 
      <input type="text" (input)="handleInput($event)">
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Tab</h1>
    <p>Try entering a space in the input above</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

TS:

```
handleInput(event: KeyboardEvent): void{
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwbjva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (keydown) instead of (input).

Answer (score -1):

I just changed your stackblitz.
You are using as the wrong way.
Try to do this.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
      <input type="text" (keyup)="handleInput($event)">
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```